# Asp.net GridView - Getting row identifier

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a page that displays orders in GridView and each row has a details- and delete-button. Most of the time everything works fine, but if new order arrives between the page refresh and button clicking, wrong order is processed.

I save unique identifier to CommandArgument, but it seems that the identifier in question isn't passed back to server, but instead some kind of counter (e.g. 5th order) and since after the arrival of new order the right one would be 6th, everything goes wrong... What's up with that?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="20" 
    EnableViewState="False" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True" 
    DataSourceID="ldsOrders" AllowPaging="True" 
    ondatabound="gvOrders_DataBound" CssClass="Gridview" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />

        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>' CommandName="Delete"
                    Text="Delete" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" CausesValidation="False" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Button ID="btnOrder" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>' CommandName="Order"
                    Text="Order" OnCommand="btnOrder_Click" CausesValidation="False" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code-Behind:

```
protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string orderID = (string)e.CommandArgument;
    da.DeleteOrder(Convert.ToInt32(orderID));
    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl, false);
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate on 'everything goes wrong.' please?

Comment: I meant that it processes the wrong row (deletes wrong one, opens wrong order, ...). For example if I wanted to delete order #123 that was on third row. If new order arrives after the page has been loaded, wrong row is deleted (eg. #124). (what would be the third row if I would have refreshed the page just before deleting)

Answer (score 0):

Without any code examples here is something to try...

Assuming that ID is the primary key - you should set that in the GridView DataKeys property.  You should not place primary keys in a viewable area.

Where you specify the CommandArgument: that should be the rowindex that is set in the RowDataBound event such that:

```
//(note this is pseudo-code, but you should get the basic idea)
if( e.row.rowtype == datarow )
{
    Button btn = (Button) e.row.findcontrol("btnDelete") ;
    btn.CommandArgument = e.row.rowIndex ;
}
```

And in the delete click event obtain the primary key from the gridview datakeys:

```
protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int orderIDIdx = (Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    int pkey = Convert.ToInt32(Gridview1.Datakeys(orderIDidx).value

    da.DeleteOrder(pkey);

    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl, false);
}
```

Obviously, add appropriate error checking where applicable.

Answer (score -1):

You should set the DataKeyNames 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" DataKeyNames="ID" .... >
```

then the command delete trigger the RowDeleting event

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdeleting.aspx

which can be used to delete the row using e.Keys[0] to retrieve the id

```
protected void Gridview1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    Int orderID = Convert.ToInt32(e.Keys[0].ToString());
    da.DeleteOrder(Convert.ToInt32(orderID));
}
```